# Lognormal Distribution, mean and variance of logarithm of distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

Let Y be a lognormally distributed random variable with mean $\mu_Y$ and standard deviation $\sigma_Y$. Assume $\ln(Y)$ is normally distributed with mean $\u$ and variance $\sigma^2$. According to my source, the mean of the lognormal distribution satisfies

$\mu_Y=\ln(\frac{\mu\sigma}{\sqrt{1+w}})$

and variance $\sigma^{2}_Y=\ln(1+w)$

where $w=(\sigma_Y/\mu_Y)^2$.

I am questioning the correctness of this result. I have attempted to derive this formula as follows.

We know that if Y is the logarithm of the normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, then the mean of Y is given by

(1)  $\mu_Y=e^{\mu + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2}$, and

(2)  $\sigma_Y^2=(e^{\sigma^2} -1)\mu_Y^2$

Setting $w$ the same value as above, the second equation implies that $w=e^{\sigma^2} -1$ so that $\sigma^2=\ln(w+1)$ just as claimed above.

On the other hand, now that we have $\sigma^2$, we substitute this value into equation (1) we get

$\mu_Y=e^{\mu + \frac{1}{2}\ln(w+1)}$, which, to my algebra, yields $\mu =\ln(\frac{\mu_Y}{\sqrt{w+1}})$.

> Hoping that somebody here can verify my sanity, or explain why the formula for the mean given in my source is correct.

Comment: What is "the mean of the logarithm of a distribution"? Do you mean "the mean of the logarithm of a random variable"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have
$$
\mu_Y=e^{\mu+\sigma^2/2}
$$
and
$$
\sigma_Y^2=(e^{\sigma^2}-1)e^{2\mu+\sigma^2}
$$
(see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution)).
Hence
$$
w=\frac{\sigma_Y^2}{\mu_Y^2}=e^{\sigma^2}-1
\quad \Longrightarrow \quad \sigma^2=\ln(w+1).
$$
Now
$$
\ln\mu_Y=\mu+\frac{\sigma^2}2=\mu+\frac{\ln(w+1)}2=\mu+\ln(\sqrt{w+1})
$$
yielding
$$
\mu=\ln\frac{\mu_Y}{\sqrt{w+1}}.
$$
So you are correct.

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be some confusion here.

It seems you have an unstated $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ with

- $Y=\exp(X)$, not a logarithm, and
- $\mu_Y=e^{\mu + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2}$ and
- $\sigma^2_Y=(e^{\sigma^2} -1)e^{2\mu + \sigma^2}=(e^{\sigma^2} -1) \mu_Y^2$.

If you say $w=\frac{\sigma^2_Y}{\mu^2_Y}=e^{\sigma^2} -1$ then

- $\sigma^2  = \log_e(1+w)$ and
- $\mu = \log_e(\mu_Y) - \frac{1}{2}\log_e(1+w) = \log_e\left(\frac{\mu_Y}{\sqrt{1+w}}\right)$

as in your final expression; your source seems to have a stray $\sigma$ and missing a subscript $Y$.

Comment: Henry, I agree that my statement of the question was a little bit sloppy. I've corrected it.

Comment: Also, I accepted Stas' answer but I upvoted yours to award you points as well. They were both equally good so I flipped a coin to determine which one to accept.